# 'x' is defined as 'y', but compiler can not match 'y' with 'x', why?

Tags: haskell

I have a type defined as such:

`data People = People [[String]]`

and a function definition that looks like this:

```
myFunction :: ([String], People) -> (Int, Int) -> People
myFunction first_tuple second_tuple = filter (myPredicate (fst second_tuple) (fst first_tuple)) (snd first_tuple)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[[String]]'
              with actual type `People'
* In the second argument of `filter', namely `(snd first_tuple)'
```

This has me truly stumped because I tried to be explicit as possible with my brackets and `People` is clearly defined as `[[String]]`. What is causing this and why is it the case?

Here is the type signature of `myPredicate`:

```
myPredicate :: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> Bool
```

Comment: please include the definition of `myPredicate` - also right now your code is contains multiple errors (`MyFunction` should be `myFunction`) , if you are filtering `People` by `[[String]]` you need to convert the latter to `People` by applying the constructor.

Comment: `People` is defined in terms of `[[String]]` but is not the same as, nor interchangeable with, `[[String]]`. It is most definitely not defined **as** `[[String]]`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I've edited my post to include the type definition of `MyPredicate`

Comment: If you want a name that is *defined as* some type, use a `type` declaration: `type People = [[String]]`

Comment: `type People = [[String]]` creates the alias you are expecting; `data People = People [[String]]` create an *isomorphic*, but distinct, type.

Answer (score 3):

First of all function names as well as variable names have to begin with a lower case letter. So

- `MyFunction` => `myFunction`
- `MyPredicate` => `myPredicate`

As you defined

```
myPredicate :: Int -> [String] -> [String] -> Bool
```

<strike>The third argument of `myPredicate` should be `[String]`, where you supply a `People` when you use the function.</strike>
You use this function with `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` - `a` is specialized to `[String]` thus the 2nd argument of `filter` must be `[[String]]` but you supply `People` which is something different.

Now you have 3 options

1. Change `data People..` to `type People = [[String]]`
2. Use pattern matching in the function definition

   ```
   myFunction :: ([String], People) -> (Int, Int) -> People
   myFunction (strs,People ps) (x,_) = filter (myPredicate x strs) ps
   ```
3. write a custom `filterPeople` function where

   ```
   filterPeople :: ([String] -> Bool) -> People -> People
   ```

Comment: Actually, is not the myPredicate the compiler is complaining about, but the filter function that expects an array as second argument. I agree with you suggested options, though.

Comment: Trying `myFunction (strs, People ps) (a1, a2) = filter ((myPredicate a1 strs) (state))` results in an error: `* Couldn't match type [Char] with Char Expected type: [String] Actual type: [[String]]`

Answer (score 3):

`People` is defined in terms of `[[String]]` but is not the same as, nor interchangeable with, `[[String]]`.

A data type declaration creates a type that is distinct from all other types. In this simple case, `People` can be thought of as a wrapped and tagged `[[String]]`. You need explicit wrapping and unwrapping in order to go from `People` to `[[String]]` and back.

Very briefly, the wrapping operation is spelled `People`:

```
p = People [["Mary", "Smith"], ["John", "Starke"]]
```

and unnwrapping is done with pattern matching:

```
printPeople (People ppl) = print ppl
```

If you want a named type that is *defined as* some other type, use a type declaration:

```
type People = [[String]]
```

In this case, `People` becomes fully synonymous with `[[String]]`.